# Efficient frontier doesn't look good

Tags: python, portfolio

Hi I'm trying to draw an efficient frontier. Below is what I used.
returns parameter consists of 9 column returns of portfolio. I selected 10,000 portfolios and this is how my efficient frontier looked like. This is not the usual frontier shape that is familiar to us.

Can somone kindly explain me the issue.

```
def monteCarlo_Simulation(returns):

    #returns=returns.drop("Date")
    returns=returns/100
    stocks=list(returns)
    stocks1=list(returns)
    stocks1.insert(0,"ret")
    stocks1.insert(1,"stdev")
    stocks1.insert(2,"sharpe")
    print (stocks)
    #calculate mean daily return and covariance of daily returns
    mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
    #print (mean_daily_returns)
    cov_matrix = returns.cov()

    #set number of runs of random portfolio weights
    num_portfolios = 10000


    #set up array to hold results
    #We have increased the size of the array to hold the weight values for each stock
    results = np.zeros((4+len(stocks)-1,num_portfolios))

    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        #select random weights for portfolio holdings
        weights = np.array(np.random.random(len(stocks)))
        #rebalance weights to sum to 1
        weights /= np.sum(weights)

        #calculate portfolio return and volatility
        portfolio_return = np.sum(mean_daily_returns * weights) * 252
        portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)

        #store results in results array
        results[0,i] = portfolio_return
        results[1,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        #store Sharpe Ratio (return / volatility) - risk free rate element excluded for simplicity
        results[2,i] = results[0,i] / results[1,i]
        #iterate through the weight vector and add data to results array
        for j in range(len(weights)):
            results[j+3,i] = weights[j]

    print (results.T.shape)
    #convert results array to Pandas DataFrame
    results_frame = pd.DataFrame(results.T,columns=stocks1)

    #locate position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
    max_sharpe_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['sharpe'].idxmax()]
    #locate positon of portfolio with minimum standard deviation
    min_vol_port = results_frame.iloc[results_frame['stdev'].idxmin()]

    #create scatter plot coloured by Sharpe Ratio
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.scatter(results_frame.stdev,results_frame.ret,c=results_frame.sharpe,cmap='RdYlBu')
    plt.xlabel('Volatility')
    plt.ylabel('Returns')
    plt.colorbar()
    #plot red star to highlight position of portfolio with highest Sharpe Ratio
    plt.scatter(max_sharpe_port[1],max_sharpe_port[0],marker=(2,1,0),color='r',s=1000)
    #plot green star to highlight position of minimum variance portfolio
    plt.scatter(min_vol_port[1],min_vol_port[0],marker=(2,1,0),color='g',s=1000)

    print(max_sharpe_port)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code has obvious indentation errors. Please [edit] to fix -- in the desktop version of this site, paste your code, select the pasted block, and type ctrl-K to format it correctly as code.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely not the graph or code, that is messed up - but your input. Try to play around with the assets. It could be that the assets you included in your optimization algorithm are highly positively correlated - causing there to be neglectable effects of diversification. This, in turn, affects the shape of your efficient frontier.

**EDIT:**

If this is not the source of the problem. Maybe retry the program with the following line of code:

```
def monteCarlo_Simulation(returns):
    noa = len(tickers)
    random_returns = []
    random_volatility = []

    for i in range (10000):
        weights = np.random.random(noa)
        weights = weights / np.sum(weights)
        random_returns.append(np.sum(returns.mean()*weights)*252)
        random_volatility.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(returns.cov()*252, weights))))

    random_returns = np.array(random_returns)
    random_volatility = np.array(random_volatility)

    fig_random = plt.figure(figsize = [6,4])
    plt.scatter(random_volatility, random_returns,
                c= random_returns / random_volatility, marker = '.')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Expected volatility')
    plt.ylabel('Expected return')
    plt.colorbar(label='Sharpe ratio')
    plt.title('Mean Variance Analysis Plot')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I solved it by looking at NaN values, some companies had their IPO much later, some in the same year. Hence you would need to either collect data as recent as the latest IPO in your stock portfolio. Or eliminate all the stocks that did not IPO before the date you retrieved the data.